# Run bash script as if I it was executed from a different directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Maybe the title is a bit "stupid" but I do not know how to express my question and how to search for the question also, even if it is something very simple.

I have a set of scripts that produce a set of reports in the folder they are executed by. For example I have the script "my_script.sh" in the folder /a/folder/ and in this folder a set of output is stored. Since I have a lot of experiments that I want to let them run for the whole week I was thinking of creating a bash script that will call all the other scripts.
But the output will be stored in the folder that the global script is present.

For example:

```
 /global/folder/global_script.sh
```

---> All the output is stored in this folder.

The global_script.sh may contain something like this:

```
/experiments/exp1/script1.sh >report1.txt
/experiments/exp1/script2.sh >report2.txt
/experiments/exp1/script2.sh >report3.txt
```

And I want the output of the bash scripts to be in their folder and not in the global folder.

Currently I am doing this manually navigating to the folder and executing the script.

(Ok I can change the code and use absolute paths! but is any better way to do that? )

Comment: You have the scripts location to execute. Now where is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

you could change the working directory before you execute each script, or redirect the output to the directory you want:

```
cd /experiments/exp1/
sh /experiments/exp1/script1.sh >report1.txt
```

or

```
sh /experiments/exp1/script1.sh > /experiments/exp1/report1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with simply changing directory?

```
cd /experiments/exp1
./script1.sh >report1.txt
./script2.sh >report2.txt
./script2.sh >report3.txt
```

Comment: Ok I dont know..... temporal brain-lock. I am ashamed of this question now... Thanks to both of you by the way :)

Comment: Its better to leave this question ? or should I delete it ?

Comment: @nikosdi: Just leave it. No worries. The answers might help future readers brought by search engines.